# M4 macros in the 3rd-party aclocal directory are not found

Tags: c++, build, gtk, autotools, automake

I have locally installed a newer version of `automake` (1.15) on a system which I do not have root access to. The local directory's bin folder is the first directory in my `PATH`.

I have also locally installed `gtk+-2.0`, and I now want to build and install an application which requires `gtk` as a dependency, i.e. the `configure.ac` script for my desired application contains:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK, [gtk+-2.0 >= 2.0])
```

To ensure the m4 macros are found, I copied the `.m4` file in `gtk_install_dir/share/aclocal` into the location that `aclocal --print` specifies (`automake_install_dir/share/aclocal/`).

I also set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=gtk_install_dir/lib/pkgconfig`.

However, when I run:

```
$ libtoolize
$ aclocal
$ autoconf
$ automake
$ ./configure
```

I get an error message:

```
./configure: line 13106: syntax error near unexpected token `GTK,'
./configure: line 13106: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK, gtk+-2.0 >= 2.0)'
```

Running `aclocal --verbose` I can clearly see that there is no mention of gtk, so it is clearly not finding the gtk+ macros.

I have not used these build tools before, am I missing something? I seemingly can't get the configure script to recognise that gtk is installed!

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I can confirm that `pkg-config` knows where my gtk installation is:

```
$ pkg-config --print-variables gtk+-2.0
exec_prefix
gtk_binary_version
...
```

Also confirmed by `pkg-config --debug gtk+-2.0`. If `pkg-config` knows all about the package, why doesn't autotools?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that **pkg-config-devel** or similarly named package is installed. Without that, aclocal can't find the *macro* `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` which is needed for `./configure` to invoke `pkg-config`.

The software you're trying to build *might* have a `pkg.m4` file in a subdirectory such as `m4/`, but if it was not configured correctly it might not actually notice that, try using `autoreconf -fis -I m4` if there is such a directory.

Comment: Can someone please upvote this comment. This is the only thing that solved my problem!!! Was so hard to find via google